# Wolfram Alpha computation of exponents

Tags: exponentiation, wolfram-alpha

I am a bit confused by a Wolfram Alpha.
In my calculations I had a term like $x^{(3/2)}$ which I wrote as $\sqrt{x^3}$. As silly mistakes happen quite often to me, I often double check stuff like this by typing $x^{(3/2)}-\sqrt{x^3} $ into Wolfram Alpha with the expecation to see $0$.
The result, which I uploaded here, did surprise me though.
Can someone explain what is going on?
I suspect that the two terms are being calculated numerically in different ways, which leads to slight differences.
[image]

Comment: Likely roundoff error.

Comment: Wolfram seems to interpret rational exponents with root first. For example $x^{\frac{3}{2}}-(\sqrt{x})^3$ is returned as being exactly $0$ for all $x$